# Difference between Photo Library and Media Library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I'm saving or fetching or creating(using camera) photo, we need to ask permissions for the respective action. For that we need to give photo library description, media library description, photo library additions description, camera usage description etc., what is the difference between those description. Can anyone tell. Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the difference is quiet simple:
Photo Gallery Description: The description for the Photos Gallery.
Media Gallery Description: The description for the Media Gallery (Photos, Audio, Video, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your information. And what about "Photo Library Additions description"

Comment: Its for write only access to photos. [cocoa keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)